# How do i release a test version of a spotify app using facebook sandbox mode?

Tags: facebook, sandbox, spotify, beta-testing

I need to  release an application in beta test on spotify using the facebook sandbox mode for authentification. Did spotify can provide me a way to release my beta test app on production ?

We want to test your app with a restricted community before release it to the public.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the html/js Spotify apps?  If so, there is no beta support at this point, other than getting your beta users to sign up for Spotify developer accounts and giving them the full codebase.

Note: I don't work for Spotify, so they may have some non-public option here for a larger developer.  Also, I have no idea what facebook sandbox mode would have to do with this.

Comment: THanks Thomas.
Spotify support has answered. They can limit the access to your application for a list of allowed people.
But infortunately since yesterday, spotify doesn't receive any apps anymore for the client desktop. So
i am stucked.